# Qt reading file and mapping to QVector very slow (crashes)

Tags: c++, qt, qfile, qvector

So what I am trying to do is read a file and map it to a two dimensional QVector. Here is my code so far

```
void dataModel::parseFileByLines()
{
QVector<QVector<QString> > dataSet;
lastError = "";
QRegExp reg(fileDelimiter);
QFile inFile(inputFile);
if (inFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)){
    QTextStream fread(&inFile);
    long totalSize = inFile.size();
    QString line;
    while(!fread.atEnd()){
        line = fread.readLine();  
        dataSet.append(line.split(reg,QString::KeepEmptyParts).toVector());
   }
}else{
   lastError = "Could not open "+inputFile+" for reading";
}
}
```

My issue is that when dealing with 1000,000 lines or more the program crashes with a message saying "This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way". Is there a more efficient way I can achieve my goal ? If so how ?

The input file may be in a format like so

ID,NAME,AGE,GENDER...etc

1,Sam,12

...

...

1000000

I would really appreciate any help or advice

Comment: The next step from here would be to run this with the debugger to find which line it's crashing on and to get a stack trace.

Comment: @MrEricSir thanks, but I already know that the bottleneck is the `dataSet.append()`. But that's my question, am I using the wrong Qt containers ? Is there another more efficient method which Qt provides to achieve what I want ? From researching I could not find anything relating to this kind of scenario.

Comment: Depends, it's not clear what your goal is from this one function. Could you elaborate on what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: A quick improvement would be to call reserve() on the vector initially. At some point it will just fail to allocate enough continuous memory, that's probably where the crash is coming from (use a debugger). Something like processing a text file with 1M lines you probably also want to move to a separate thread.

Comment: @MrEricSir So I have an application that reads in a text file. This text file can be comma,Tab or Pipe delimited. I want to map this text file to a QTableView. So the above function is supposed to do the mapping part. The `dataSet` is a two dimensional vector that represents the data structure used in my `QAbstractTableModel` implementation. Also this function is run on a separate thread

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld yes indeed its that append function. However `line.split(reg,QString::KeepEmptyParts).toVector()` this in particular is the problem. If I simply append `line` to a `QVector<QString>` as a control it runs and doesn't crash.

Comment: if you have to split the line with a simple separator I really do not see the point in using a QRegExp, regular expression can be quite consuming in terms of CPU, in general I use them only when is really necessary and this does not seem to be the case. Anyway this might explain the slow process but definetly not the crash, and the only reason  see for a crash here is a possible failure in getting a contiguos ram to allocate your qvector, so my other suggestion is to try using a QList<QList<QString>>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested this (QList) version here on my computer and it runs much faster then the QVector version and I also believe it will not crash.

```
void parseFileByLines(QString inputFile)
{
    QList<QList<QString> > dataSet;
    QString lastError = "";
    QFile inFile(inputFile);
    if (inFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)){
        QTextStream fread(&inFile);
        long totalSize = inFile.size();
        QString line;
        while(!fread.atEnd()){
            line = fread.readLine();
            QList<QString> record = line.split('\t',QString::KeepEmptyParts);
            dataSet.append(record);
        }
    }else{
        lastError = "Could not open "+inputFile+" for reading";
    }
}
```

Comment: Using QList instead of QVector will just avoid memory reallocation made by QVector, but in the end the same amount of memory is needed. For very large data sets I'd use an sqlite database or you might try with redis server if you want a cache-based store server. Storing in memory such large amounts of data is not a good idea especially when there is no pre alocation.

Comment: It is much faster and does not crash, so this would be due to the memory reallocation factor ?

Comment: Yes, the differen speed is due to the reallocation, the crashes I am not sure but likely to be a failed allocation, if you want to be sure you could try to add a try except around the allocation and catch a possibile failure, Finally remember that with the qlist your data now is faster in writing but slowlier in random reading.